# Plot multiple x variables in a single plot

Tags: r

I have multiple continuous x variables (length, diameter, weight) all measured in mm with similar value ranges, and in the same dataframe. I want a boxplot for each, but all sharing the same y axis in a single grid.

I've only been able to find out how to group by the different levels of a single x variable, or how to combine multiple plots into a single image (not a single plot). Here's a drawing of what I want:

[image: example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `ggplot`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(name, value)) + geom_boxplot()
```

Answer (score 2):

If your data frame looks something like this:

```r
set.seed(1)

df <- round(data.frame(length = rnorm(10, 5),
                       diameter = rnorm(10, 6), 
                       height = rnorm(10, 5)), 2)

df
#>    length diameter height
#> 1    4.37     7.51   5.92
#> 2    5.18     6.39   5.78
#> 3    4.16     5.38   5.07
#> 4    6.60     3.79   3.01
#> 5    5.33     7.12   5.62
#> 6    4.18     5.96   4.94
#> 7    5.49     5.98   4.84
#> 8    5.74     6.94   3.53
#> 9    5.58     6.82   4.52
#> 10   4.69     6.59   5.42
```

Then it's as easy as

```r
boxplot(df)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>